# Formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor i\sqrt{2} \rfloor $

Tags: summation

I'm trying to find a faster way to compute this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor i\sqrt{2} \rfloor $$

I doubt that there is a compact form, but there must be some way to calculate this faster than just iterating over i.
If it wasn't for the floor, it would be easy, but I don't know and can't find anything on how to solve this.

Comment: @player3236 Yes, thank you! How, did I not come across that one, I've been searching for hours..

Comment: what kind of approximation are looking for ? for large $n$ ?